# Полный dump ОЗУ Linux

Tags: linux, unix, администрирование

Подскажите какими средствами можно сделать полный дамп оперативной памяти в ОС Linux?

Comment: именно оперативной памяти (то есть микросхем памяти) или памяти процесса(виртуальную память)?

Comment: Каждого процесса

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How to dump memory image from linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119762/1321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загнать в гипервизор, потом сделать pause, потом-save.